# .NET MAUI One of the ObservableCollection property changes does not fire DataTrigger and do not make any changes of UI

Tags: .net, .net-maui

I am trying to change button color when it's pressed in the `ColectionieView` but data trigger is not firing, and do not apply any UI changes.

My XAML:

```
 <CollectionView 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" 
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" 
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never" 
        VerticalOptions="Center">
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" ItemSpacing="3" />
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Category">
                <Button Padding="10, 5" 
                        Margin="10, 15, 0, 10" 
                        BorderColor="Transparent" Background="{Binding Source={StaticResource Gray300}, ConverterParameter=0.4, Converter={StaticResource ColorToRGBAColor}}" 
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                        Text="{Binding Name}"
                        Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference TaskListPage},Path=BindingContext.CategorySelectedCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
                    <Button.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger TargetType="Button" Binding="{Binding IsActive}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Button.Triggers>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

ViewModel:

```
public partial class TaskListViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<Category> categories;

    
    public IRelayCommand<Category> CategorySelectedCommand { get; set; }


    public TaskListViewModel()
    {
        categories = new ObservableCollection<Category>();

        categories.Add(new Category { Name = "Work", IsActive = true });
        categories.Add(new Category { Name = "Personal", IsActive = false });
        categories.Add(new Category { Name = "Wishlist", IsActive = false });

        CategorySelectedCommand = new RelayCommand<Category>(CategorySelected);
    }

    private void CategorySelected(Category category)
    {
        Categories.All(c => { c.IsActive = false; return true; });
        var categoryToActivate = Categories.SingleOrDefault(x => x == category);

        if (categoryToActivate is null)
        {
            return;
        }

        categoryToActivate.IsActive = true;

        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Categories));
    }
}
```

I also tried to repopulate ObservableCollection and that helps, but I'm sure that there is can be more cleaner solution. Give advice what I need to change please.

Comment: Add to question the declaration of `Category`, and its member `IsActive`. You probably have not made `IsActive` setter do `OnPropertyChanged`, so the bound button is not told that the value changed. (Remember to always show in question all related code. In this case, the declaration of the bound property and its class are relevant.)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve property `IsActive` is part of the `Category` model. But models in general should not be able to notify that their properties are changed? Or I am wrong at this point?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "in general". To solve your problem , you need notification. So `Category` should inherit from `ObservableObject`. And `IsActive` should be an `ObservableProperty`.

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure the `Category` is an ObservableObject, such as:

```
public class Category : ObservableObject
{
    private string name;
    private bool isActive;
    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        set => SetProperty(ref name, value);
    }
    public bool IsActive
    {
        get => isActive;
        set => SetProperty(ref isActive, value);
    }
}
```

For more information, you can check the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observableobject#simple-property).